# Is it necessary to reset the query after using get_posts()?

Tags: loop, get-posts, wp-reset-postdata, wp-reset-query

Is it necessary to reset the query after using `get_posts()` ?

I have been looking at [this](http://digwp.com/2011/09/3-ways-to-reset-the-wordpress-loop/) page and I don't see any reference to `get_posts()`  ... I can't make it out for sure from [this](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/1753/when-should-you-use-wp-query-vs-query-posts-vs-get-posts) page either.

I can't see why it wouldn't be necessary ( though on my test page it doesnt cause any problems without `wp_reset_postsdata()` `wp_reset_query()' or ''rewind_posts()' ) but if it is which is the right function(s) to use.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

No. `get_posts()` does not modify global `$wp_query` variable and it doesn't need to be cleaned up.

Note that if you further use `setup_postdata()` you do need to `wp_reset_postdata()` afterwards.

Comment: would this be the same for get_post()?

Comment: @daniel Crabbe yes. `get_post()` also only retrieves data for you. It does not modify global variables either, unless you further explicitly do so (with `setup_postdata()` or whatever).